# Breaking down a Core Data Entity

Tags: ios, core-data

If I have an entity Person, and it has information like name, dateOfBirth, email and then it also has information like houseNo, street, landmark, city, country  as well.

and this entity is representing a big form on an iPad.

Is it possible to break it down into smaller entities like Address ?

and then relate Address to Person, but that will be a one to one relationship, is it Okay ?

I am asking this because too many attribues based on one form for a person is becoming complex to manage.

Comment: yes you can do this, no harm in doing this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encouraged to use a more entities to reflect the logic of your data model. This is certainly a good design principle and will provide more flexibility for future developments of your project.

However, I do not agree with your argument about complexity. In fact, a relational core data model is more complex than a flat one. Having one form referring to just one entity with a whole lot of attributes is certainly *less* complex than having relationships to other entities.

So if you think that your original data model is sufficient for your purposes, there is no good reason to change it.

Comment: Why I used the term complex was because of the corresponding JSON representations of those entities used by the applicatiosn REST API.
That things is nested and at times there are chances that we for get one or the other attribute while reading a JSON or creating one.
Just my observation.